# How to make the changes with slider in viewcontroller 2 reflecting the changes in viewcontroller 1?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uislider

I do not know how to figure out the changes of the slider value with the view controller2 in the view controller 1. I think i am calling it correctly but the values are not getting passed to the view.

I put a slider in the nib file and when i change it's value the value of the rect  height and width should change.

here's my //appdelegate.m

```
CGRect bounds        = [self.window bounds];
KaleidoTab *view    = [[KaleidoTab alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



KaleidoTabFirstViewController *vc = [[KaleidoTabFirstViewController alloc] init];
[vc setView: view];

KaleidoTabSecondViewController *vc2 = [[KaleidoTabSecondViewController alloc] init];
//[vc2 setView: view];
vc2.vc = vc;

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc, vc2];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

here's my //secondviewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KaleidoTabFirstViewController.h"
@interface KaleidoTabSecondViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UISlider *changeSize;
IBOutlet UILabel *label1; }
@property KaleidoTabFirstViewController *vc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *changeSize;
- (IBAction) changeSizeSlider:(id)sender;
```

here's //secondviewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)changeSizeSlider:(UISlider *)sender
{
/// Change label to match slider's value
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", changeSize.value];
CGFloat changeSizeCont = changeSize.value;
((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_width = changeSizeCont;
((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_height = changeSizeCont; 
}
```

kaleidotab.m has the methods for drawing the rectangles.

I synthesized the properties and everything is fine. I think there is something wrong with my firstviewcontroller object.

appreciate your time.
Thanks

Comment: This is very convoluted. Why are you creating views and assigning them to the view controllers? I'd define the view controller to use (as its view property, in a nib) the KaleidoTab view. Then, use standard MVC practice to define a data model that holds the value being manipulated byt the slider. Any view that wants to can update when the data model updates.

Comment: @MattMartel I am sure i am going the right way, with the tabbed application template i can have my viewcontrollers called whenever i want programatically, but the issue is with the secondviewcontroller that having a nib file. The value is not passing from the slider's cahngevalue to the view object vc2. Trying to figure it out but no success yet.

Comment: Is your slider label updating appropriately?

Comment: @Matt Yes, the slider's label is updating fine. but i see the changed value is not reflecting in the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using Java-like syntax rather than Objective-C syntax. You'll find it easier to diagnose issues like these if you adopt Objective-C's approach to OOP syntax:

```
// For getting property values
[objectName propertyName];

// For setting property values
[objectName setPropertyName];
```

A lot of how the iOS Framework works depends on following these conventions. Try changing your code to the following:

```
    - (IBAction)changeSizeSlider:(UISlider *)sender
    {
    // Change label to match slider's value
    [label1 text] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", [changeSize value]];

    // Var for changing size
    CGFloat changeSizeCont = [changeSize value];

    // Log to the console so that we can confirm changeSizeCont is being set appropriately
    NSLog(@"changeSizeCont = %d", changeSizeCont);


    /* I'm not used to this current syntax, this may be what's going wrong
    It's confusing to read, it should be clearer.
    I understand that you are attempting to grab the 1st view controller and
    change its view properties, I think you can drop the
    ((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_width and replace it with
    vc.view.rect_width
    vc.view.rect_height
    */
    ((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_width = changeSizeCont;
    ((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_height = changeSizeCont; 

    // Log to the console so that we can confirm the rect_width and rect_height properties are receiving the change
    NSLog("Current values for VC's view properties:");
    NSLog(@"rect_width = %d", ((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_width);
    NSLog(@"rect_width = %d", ((KaleidoTab *)vc.view).rect_height);

    }
```

This should help you head in the right direction. You'll be able to check on the console whether or not the property values are updating or not. If they are and the view isn't changing appropriately, you probably need to look at the life-cycle of the application and find out where you need to reload or update your view to reflect the changes of your view to the screen.

Comment: Make sure you read the large comment, I feel that this is where you may have your mistake.

Comment: I appreciate your time. I can see the slider's value changed in the log console. but when i switch to the firstviewcontroller tab the view is continuing with its default values. The changed values maybe being sent to the view but , i think it has to reload to make the new changes to work.

Comment: I appreciate your time though.

Comment: Try adding some code to - (void)viewWillLoad method. This method is called anytime you change between view controllers in a tabbed application. You need to set the value of the slider and the values of the rect to see the changes across the entire application.

Comment: Right now i am doing it in -viewWillAppear method.

Comment: How do i write code in the viewWillLoad method, so that it will reload its view, i am not sure of it.

Comment: The problem here is you can't be sure the other tab's ViewController's view even exists when it is not visible. This is why I suggested you create a data model that reflects the value you want to display. Accessing a ViewController's view will force it to create the view by calling loadView, etc. But a ViewController may have it's view released if it is not visible. When you switch tabs and show the other ViewController's view again, and it reloads the view, it doesn't know about the value you previously set because it is not in a data model anywhere.